# Fundamental group of connected sum for non-orientable manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

For orientable $n$-manifolds, $n\ge3$, the fundamental group of connected sum is free product of fundamental groups: $\pi_1(M\#N)=\pi_1(M)*\pi_1(N)$.

As far as I understand, for non-orientable manifolds connected sum is not quite well-defined, at least it can be non-unique (or is the problem worse than that?). Suppose $M\#N$ is one of possible realizations of connected sum (even if other non-homeomorphic realizations exist).

Does the above equality still holds for it?

If not, then: even if the manifolds decomposable as $M\#N$ can differ, don't they have the same fundamental groups?

Comment: Doesn't the usual van Kampen argument not care whether the manifold is oriented?

Comment: Thank you! Could you please make it an answer so that I can accept it? Maybe you can also comment on that even if, for example, $\mathbb CP^2\#\mathbb CP^2$ is not uniquely defined, its fundamental group is uniquely defined, right?

Comment: Another word of caution: all this only works in (real) dimension at least 2!

To flesh out the argument, we're really taking a free product fibered over $\pi_1$ of the intersection, which for dimension at least 2 is trivial.  Reversing orientation of $N$ can be thought of as the automorphism "take generators to their inverses and reverse order of (reduced) words" of $\pi_1(N)$; since $\pi_1$ of the intersection is trivial it turns out that the inclusion you're fibering over is trivial anyways, so the automorphism has no effect on the van Kampen result.

Comment: @drvitek: One needs real dimension 3 to get a free product, not 2.  In dim. 2, the collar has $\pi_1 = Z$, and (in most cases) this group includes non-trivially into the fundamental group of each side of the connected sum (which is now free, being $\pi_1$ of a surface minus a point).  For instance, if you take a connected sum of a closed orientable surface $M^g$ of positive genus with $\mathbb{R}P^2$, then you get a surface with universal cover $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $\pi_1$ of the connected sum is torsion-free.  This is not $\pi_1 (M^g) * \pi_1 \mathbb{R}P^2$, since that would contain torsion.

Comment: Gosh darn it, @lie341, you're right.  I totally forgot about the collar and was just focusing on the inclusions $S^n \hookrightarrow M, N$ on either side.

Comment: FWIW the statement in the first paragraph is only true if dimension is at least 3.